# How can $\lim\limits_{\theta\to0} \theta^{\frac1x -1} \tan(\theta^{\frac1x})$ be evaluated?

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{\theta\to0} \theta^{\frac1x -1} \tan(\theta^{\frac1x}) \;\;\;\;\; (x > 1)
$$

I've tried L'Hôpital's rule with $\theta$ in the denominator, but successive applications seems to only lead to more complex expressions. Interestingly, it seems that each application of L'Hôpital's rule will produce another limit to which L'Hôpital's is applicable.

Can I use this fact somehow to analytically evaluate the limit?

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary, but I find things easier to see if I let $w=\theta^{1/x}$. Then $\theta=w^x$, and we end up looking at $w^{1-x}\tan w$.

We want to find
$$\lim_{w\to 0^+} w^{1-x}\tan w.$$
Rewrite this as
$$\lim_{w\to 0^+} w^{2-x} \frac{\tan w}{w}.$$
Now things will likely be clear. The answer is $x$-dependent.

**Remark:** We could instead write immediately that our function is
$$\theta^{\frac{2}{x}-1} \frac{\tan(\theta^{\frac{1}{x}})}{\theta^{\frac{1}{x}}},$$ and proceed immediately to the conclusion. However, I think that the preliminary "cleaning up" of the answer helps one see things more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\theta^{1/x}$ ($y^x=\theta$), so as $\theta\to0$, then $y\to0$. Now

Note that
$$
\theta^{1/x-1}=\theta^{1/x}\theta^{-1}=yy^{-x}=y^{1-x}
$$
Thus the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{y\to0}y^{1-x}\tan y
$$

Comment: How does this answer differ from the one already given by Andre Nicolas?

Comment: I wrote it independently (almost at the same time he was writing his) but since I am slow at typing, his post appeared sooner.

Comment: Thanks for this follow-up.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying the limit is $0$ for all values of $x$? If we let $x=2$ then the limit is  $\lim_{\theta\to0} \theta^{-\frac12} \tan(\theta^{\frac12}) = 1$

Comment: You are right. I admit that I was wrong.

Comment: Alas, it seems that your version of the limit has the same annoying property of the original. It can easily be rewritten in a form to which L'Hôpital's rule's rule is applicable (I'm thinking $\lim_{y\to0} \frac{y\tan(y)}{y^{x}}$), but successive applications seem to only yield more complex expressions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not using the fact that $\lim_{y\to0}\tan y/y=1$. As Andre said in his answer, the answer will be $x$-dependent.

Comment: I'm failing to see where that fact can be used. The limit can be rewritten as $\lim_{y\to0} y^{2-x} \frac{\tan(y)}{y}$, but even here that substitution is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to realize is this limit doesn't exist. That's because $\theta \to 0$ allows negative values of $\theta.$ For such $\theta,$ $\theta^{1/x}$ is not defined for most values of $x.$ So we need to change that limit sign to $\lim_{\theta \to 0^+}.$

That out of the way, note the expression equals

$$\tag 1 \theta^{(2/x)-1}\frac{\tan \theta^{1/x}}{\theta^{1/x}}.$$

As $\theta \to 0^+, \theta^{1/x}\to 0.$ Recalling $\lim_{u\to 0} (\tan u)/u = 1,$ (this follows from $(\sin u)/u \to 1$), we see the fraction in $(1)$  $\to 1$ as $\theta\to 0^+.$ So we don't have to worry about it.

We're left thinking about $\theta^{(2/x)-1}.$ This blows up if $(2/x)-1< 0,$ is identically $1$ if $(2/x)-1 = 0,$ and $\to 0$ if $(2/x)-1>0.$ Thus the limit in $(1)$ doesn't exist if $x>2,$ equals $1$ if $x=2,$ and equals $0$ if $1<x<2.$